# AO map is pixelated. Any way to fix it? (pictures below)

Tags: texturing, image

My low poly map is fairly big and that is probably the reason. I created an image of 4096*4096 and here is the **result**:

[image]

Is there any good way to create a high-quality ambient occlusion map for models like this, or is upping the image resolution the only way?

**Would like to make it look it like this:**

[image]

Ambient occlusion has been turned on with strength of 5 in the picture above

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try increasing samples for AO. If you use Raytrace method then Samples are present as property, if Approximate - then try to decrease Error and increase Correction. Baking time will increase.

Answer (score 2):

**Properties** panel > **World** tab > **Gather** options : enable **Falloff** then play with the **Distance** and **Strength** values.

Do your test AO bakes at 5 **Samples** and when you are happy with the result then up the **Samples** to 20 or so for the final bake.

Note, enabling or not the Ambient Occlussion option in the World tab will make no difference to the bake. The Gather options will be greyed out but they can still be changed.

Normally AO bakes are greyscale, if that is what you want then put a check against **Normalised** in the Bake panel.

[image]